# on Localhost, chrome is redirecting to another project base_url

Tags: google-chrome, browser, next.js, localhost

In my other Next.js project, I have to redirect users from `/` to `/home/base`.

```
async redirects() {
    return [
      {
        source: "/home",
        destination: "/home/sales",
        permanent: true,
        basePath: false,
      },
      {
        source: "/",
        destination: "/home/sales",
        permanent: true,
        basePath: false,
      },
    ];
  },
```

In my current project, it is doing the same although I have cleared the cache, session, localstorage on developer tools Application.

How can I solve this?

`I actually do not want to clear browsing data for all sites because I do not want to get signed out of some other websites.`

Comment: Have you tried closing and opening chrome again? Or rebooting your system? Or waiting for some minutes so the cache gets invalidated?

Comment: I did all. I have this problem for more than 2 days. I have rebooted my computer. but did not help

Comment: I finally cleared browsing data for all sites. It got fixed

Comment: see in this case try another browsers for this kind of stuff, I personally use 4 browsers at a time for different purpose.. I will suggest chrome and Firefox is good for developers. so you can pick anyone of this to run your project (set on default). and other stuff on different browser it will also speed up your work..